# Menu ( onclick help ) - css

Tags: css, menu

Ok I have now virtually fixed our menu system.

The only Issue I have now, seemingly is onclick change menu item state to ACTIVE

So here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/6pxaE/

Essentially, onclick I need the menu item clicked to change to:background color #ec008c and color to #fff with no text shadow. As seen in my Fiddle Above.

Everything else seems to work fine.

Any help appreciated. No JS please

Comment: When you click a link, you will be taken to another page. You either want to add a `class` of something like `current` to the clicked button *on the new page* (to show the user what page they're on), or I don't understand.

Comment: Thirtydot, I am such a TWOT ! How bloody stupid of me, sorry. I am Thick as Pig Sh*t ... im working on one file.. and forgot to add the class = current or active grrr Cheers

Comment: It's no problem. Mistakes like that happen to everyone, at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming what you want is to highlight the currently active page in the navigation, I think [this is still the easiest way](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css) to accomplish what you want.

Would that work?

Comment: I was trying to avoid id's but looks like its a given. Cheers

Comment: Yes, this would be easy to do with JavaScript, but it sounds like that's not your first choice.

Comment: This is what I would use, too. +1.

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

To make all of your 'active' states pink-ish, the following worked on your last lines of CSS:

```
.white ul li a:active, .white li a:active{ background-color:#ec008c;color:#fff;display:block;text-shadow: none !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExUdM/

I only tested this in Chome, Firefox, and IE9

Comment: Isnt working for me on FF9 , had tried that earlier ... I must be missing somethning. I think perhaps a combination of your fix and g_thom is the go thanks